# RX Java Single not returning from Single.merge

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x

I have several api calls (Rx singles) that i want to combine into a single Single. I'm using Single.merge to try combine the result of these calls but when i subscribe to the response i'm getting an empty array as the subscribe has already happened. I call the HealthChecker expecting that the subscribe will return the list of results:

```
     new HealthChecker(vertx)
        .getHealthChecks(endpoints)
        .subscribe(messages -> {
            log.info("Completed health check {}", messages);
            routingContext.response()
                          .putHeader("content-type", "text/json")
                          .end(messages.toString());
        });
```

The health checker class performs the logic:

```
public class HealthChecker {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HealthChecker.class);

    private Vertx vertx;
    private WebClient client;

    public HealthChecker(Vertx vertx) {
        this.vertx = vertx;
        client = WebClient.create(vertx);
    }

    public Single<List<String>> getHealthChecks(JsonArray endpoints) {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {

            List<Single<String>> healthChecks = endpoints
                .stream()
                .map(endpoint -> getHealthStatus(client, endpoint.toString()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

            return consumeHealthChecks(healthChecks).blockingGet();

        });
    }

    private Single<List<String>> consumeHealthChecks(List<Single<String>> healthChecks) {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

            Single.merge(healthChecks)
                  .timeout(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                  .subscribe(message -> {
                      log.info("Got health check {}", message);
                      messages.add(message);
                  }, error -> {
                      log.info("Timeout - could not get health check");

                  });

            return messages;
        });
    }

    private Single<String> getHealthStatus(WebClient client, String endpoint) {
        log.info("getting endpoint {}", endpoint);

        return client
            .getAbs(endpoint)
            .rxSend()
            .map(HttpResponse::bodyAsString)
            .map(response -> response);

    }
}
```

I expect the return value to be a list except all i get is an empty list and then the results come after. Here is the log:

```
09:12:06.235 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - getting endpoint http://localhost:5000/status
09:12:06.241 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - getting endpoint http://localhost:5001/status
09:12:06.241 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - getting endpoint http://localhost:5002/status
09:12:06.241 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - getting endpoint http://localhost:5003/status
09:12:06.241 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - getting endpoint http://localhost:5004/status
09:12:06.300 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthCheckVerticle - Completed health check []
09:12:06.688 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - Got health check {"isHealthy":true}
09:12:06.844 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - Got health check {"isHealthy":true}
09:12:06.898 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - Got health check {"isHealthy":false}
09:12:07.072 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - Got health check {"isHealthy":true}
09:12:07.255 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-1] INFO  sys.health.HealthChecker - Got health check {"isHealthy":true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `fromCallable` and `blockingGet`? Also you fire off the `merge` without actually waiting for it to run to completion, hence the empty list. Instead, compose over the inner `Single`s:

```java
public Single<List<String>> getHealthChecks(JsonArray endpoints) {
    return Single.defer(() -> {

        List<Single<String>> healthChecks = endpoints
            .stream()
            .map(endpoint -> getHealthStatus(client, endpoint.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return consumeHealthChecks(healthChecks);
    });
}

private Single<List<String>> consumeHealthChecks(List<Single<String>> healthChecks) {
    return Single.merge(healthChecks)
                 .timeout(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                 .toList();
}
```

Comment: i thought that i needed to call blocking get to get the value before it is returned, hence the subscribe. Still learning rx, this really helped thanks. I understand now that i can return the single.merge to list instead of incorrectly subscribing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```java
    private Single<List<String>> consumeHealthChecks(List<Single<String>> healthChecks) {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

            Single.merge(healthChecks)
                .timeout(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribe(message -> {
                    log.info("Got health check {}", message);
                    messages.add(message);
                }, error -> {
                    log.info("Timeout - could not get health check");
                });

            return messages;
    });
}
```

You are creating an empty list, then returning it from the lambda, such that the Single returned from `consumeHealthChecks` is a Single of empty list...

What I presume you want to do is something like this:

```java
    private Single<List<String>> mergeHealthChecks(List<Single<String>> healthChecks) {
      return Single.merge(healthChecks)
                .timeout(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
```

And then use it like so:

```java
    private void consumeHealthChecks() {
        Single<List<String>> healthChecks = new HealthChecker(vertx)
                .getHealthChecks(endpoints);

        mergeHealthChecks(healthChecks)
                .subscribe(message -> {
                    log.info("Merged and consumed all health checks. Final health check: ", message);
                }, error ->  {
                    log.info("Timeout - could not merge and consume health checks");
                });
    }
```

Note, when you use `Single.merge` you will only get the result of the final merged single in the subscribe success callback, so, if you want to log each message as it is successfully consumed, you'll want to hook up a side effecting call to log the message using `doOnSuccess` before your subscribe call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although this would work, the accepted answer fulfils the existing flow and returns back the `Single<List<String>>`

Comment: No worries, good to have 2 perspectives on it the accepted answer is correct, however this solution also gives you a Single<List<String>> (see the mergeHealthChecks method above)